# Error on Flask-migrate with application factory

Tags: python, flask, factory-pattern, flask-migrate, flask-cli

run.py

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = create_app()
    application.run()
```

manage.py

```
from flask_migrate import MigrateCommand, Manager

from run import create_app


manager = Manager(create_app())
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```

When I run: python manage.py db init

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 6, in <module>
    manager = Manager(create_app())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

When I run: flask db init

```
Usage: flask db init [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate Flask application. You did not provide the FLASK_APP environment variable.

For more information see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/
```

I try to export FLASK_APP as run, run.py, run.create_app, run:create_app(), yet I still get the error shown above.  What is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to run the Flask-Migrate commands. The newer method uses the Flask CLI, the older uses Flask-Script. Since you don't seem to have Flask-Script installed, I'm going to assume that you intend to use the Flask CLI.

So you need to throw away `manage.py` since that only applies to Flask-Script. Then move your `application` variable to the global scope:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    return app

application = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

Then set your `FLASK_APP` variable:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=run.py
```

And now you should be able to run the application with `flask run`, and the database commands with `flask db <command>`.

Answer (score 3):

`flask_migrate` will attempt to use Manager from `flask-script`, but only if `flask-script` is installed.

Simply do, and it should work. You can also import directly from `flask_script`.

`pip install flask_script`

**manage.py**

```
from flask_migrate import MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager
from run import create_app

app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```